# What Would I Want To Use To Have A Persistent Notification Show Up When I Access Specific Pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to make an extension that, when you go to some sites, you have a timer pop up on your screen.

I've been looking at the documentation, but I wouldn't say that its been particularly useful for a new extension builder like myself.

What I've gathered is that I would want to use a chrome.notification - which I've implemented. However, instead of the notification being persistent and being modified on the spot, it spams notifications, which is not what I want. Would I want to use a popup, notification, something else, or is this not even possible?

```
let test = 0
var myfunc = setInterval(function() {
// code goes here
    test += 1
  notification = new Notification("Test Notification", {
    icon: '48.png',
    body: test
    });
}, 1000)
```

Comment: The closest thing extensions can do is add a DOM element in the page using their content script.

Comment: That is because you're creating a new notification each second, instead of that, [update the existing notification](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-update)